# How can I change the backdrop filter I have set in CSS with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working to create a virtual microscope using hotkeys to operate it. The file movingImg has a switch statement that calls on functions when a certain key is pressed. So far I can move the image and the move is conveyed to the user with animated arrows.

When you first look into a microscope the image is never in focus, you almost always have to zoom in with core or fine focus. To emulate this I set the background filter of the image to blur(6px) and also change the brightness. I want to be able to increment/decrement the blur on the image with a certain key.

To move the image left, right, up, and down I was able to use this piece of code I found somewhere online `document.getElementById('cellmic').style.left=parseInt(bioImage.style.left)-2 +'px';` I figure I could do the same thing with `style.backdropFilter` but it did not work.

It would be appreciated if I could get any direction on how to slowly increment or decrement the blur filter with a certain key. Below is what I have so far, the black lines are just for me to be able to see my layout.

```js
/*Javascript function to move image left/right up/down, animate the move on the screen with a button animation, and to focus the image.
We ca do this using the EnentListener keydown to call to a switch statement to figure out exactly which key the user has pressed using keycodes.
Depending on which key left/right up/down the switch statment will execute the functions needed. */


var bioImage=null;
    //function to select image and buttons
    //keydown event listener will call getKeyAndMove
    //once a key has been pressed down
    function init() {
        bioImage=document.getElementById('cellmic'); 
        view=document.getElementById('grid5');
        bioImage.style.position='relative';
        bioImage.style.left='0px';
        bioImage.style.top='0px';
        document.addEventListener('keydown', getKeyAndMove);
    }

    //Switch statement to call for correct button pressed
    function getKeyAndMove(e){              
        var key_code=e.which||e.keyCode;
        switch(key_code){
            case 37: //left arrow key
                moveLeft();
                animateLeft();
                break;
            case 38: //Up arrow key
                moveUp();
                animateUp();
                break;
            case 39: //right arrow key
                moveRight();
                animateRight();
                break;
            case 40: //down arrow key
                moveDown();
                animateDown();
                break;  
            case 49: //number 1 key
                coreOut();
                break;  
            case 50: //number 2 key
                coreIn();
                break;
            case 189: //minus key
                fineOut();
                break;
            case 187: //equal or plus key
                fineIn();
                break;
            case 85: // key
                brightnessUp();
                break;
            case 68: //d key
                brightnessDown();   

        }
    }

        //Functions for left button
        //Styles the images to move in a given direction 2px
        function moveLeft() {
            bioImage.style.left=parseInt(bioImage.style.left)+2 +'px';
        }

        //In the CSS file the arrow keys are all set to paused in the animation attribute.
        //When a button is pressed on the keyboard the corresponding arrow is set to running 
        //so it's animation will happen on screen. To see the code for the animation look at 
        //for the keyframes in CSS file. 
        function animateLeft() {
            document.getElementById("left").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        }

        //Functions for up button
        function moveUp() {
            bioImage.style.top=parseInt(bioImage.style.top)+2 +'px';
        } 

        function animateUp() {
            document.getElementById("up").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        }

        //Functions for right button
        function moveRight() {
            bioImage.style.left=parseInt(bioImage.style.left)-2 +'px';
        }

        function animateRight() {
            document.getElementById("right").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        }

        //Functions for down button
        function moveDown() {
            bioImage.style.top=parseInt(bioImage.style.top)-2 +'px';
        }

        function animateDown() {
            document.getElementById("down").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
        }

        //Function for 1 and 2 key
        //This styles the image's backdrop filter. In the CSS file the backdrop filter is set to blur(6px).
        //When the user presses key 1 we want the blur to decrease. When the user presses key 2 we want the blur to increase.
        function coreOut() {
            view.style.backdropFilter=parseInt(view.style.backdropFilter)+'blur('+1+'px)';
        }

        function coreIn() {
           
        }

        //Function for minus and plus key
        //This styles the image's opacity In the CSS file the opacity is set to 0.6.
        //When the user presses the minus key we want the opacity to decrease. 
        //When the user presses the plus key we want the opacity to increase.
        //Opacity can make the image completely invisible so we may need to look at other options. 
        //Or we can add some sort of try catch that doesn't allow the user to go past a certain opacity.
        function fineOut() {

        }

        function fineIn() {

        }

        function brightnessUp() {

        }

        function brightnessDown() {
            
        }




        window.onload=init;
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: opacity(0.6);
}

/* Grid Layout */

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 2.9fr 0.2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.4fr 2.7fr 0.8fr;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
  
.grid {
    border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
}

#grid5 {
    backdrop-filter: blur(6px) brightness(86%);
}

/* Keyframes animation */

#up {
    animation: motionUp 0.3s alternate 0s 4 paused;
}

@keyframes motionUp {
    from {
        top: 15px;
    }

    to {
        top: 5px;
    }
}

#left {
    animation: motionLeft 0.3s alternate 0s 2 paused;
}

@keyframes motionLeft {
    from {
        left: 35px;
    }

    to {
        left: 25px;
    }
}

#right {
    animation: motionRight 0.3s alternate 0s 2 paused;
}

@keyframes motionRight {
    from {
        right: 35px;
    }

    to {
        right: 25px;
    }
}

#down {
    animation: motionDown 0.3s alternate 0s 2 paused;
}

@keyframes motionDown {
    from {
        bottom: 55px;
    }

    to {
        bottom: 45px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<header>

</header>

<body>
    <div id="zoom">
        <img id="cellmic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/03/ef/7c/03ef7cf7f7bae75563e62bb5f371c44b.jpg" height="775" width="2048" alt="">
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid" id="grid1"></div>
        <div class="grid" id="grid2"><img id="up" src="img/double-up.png" height="50" width="50" alt=""></div>
        <div class="grid" id="grid3"></div> 
        <div class="grid" id="grid4"><img id="left" src="img/double-left.png" height="50" width="50" alt=""></div>
        <div id="grid5"></div>
        <div class="grid" id="grid6"><img id="right" src="img/double-right.png" height="50" width="50" alt=""></div> 
        <div class="grid" id="grid7"></div>
        <div class="grid" id="grid8"><img id="down" src="img/double-down.png" height="50" width="50" alt=""></div>
        <div class="grid" id="grid9"></div>
      </div>  
    
</body>

<script src='JSfiles/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='JSfiles/focusWheel.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='JSfiles/movingImg.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have here: `parseInt(view.style.backdropFilter)+'blur('+1+'px)'`, if we breakdown what it will get-- the value at `view.style.backdropFilter`, which will be something like `"blur(3px)"`, which will evaluate to `NaN` when parsed as an integer.  You then add this to some numbers an strings, which is essentially `NaN+'blur('+1+'px)'`, which will evaluate to `"NaNblur(1px)"`, which obviously won't work.

Your example involves a *lot* of code-- not quite a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As such, I just created a small example of how to accomplish this below. I stored the current blur level in a data attribute to avoid having to try to ascertain it from the current value each time.  Then I increment it, update the dataset, and update the `element.style.backdropFilter` value with `blur(${increasedLevel}px`:

```js
function increaseBlur() {
  const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
  const currentLevel = parseInt(overlay.dataset.blurlevel, 10);
  const increasedLevel = currentLevel + 1;
  overlay.dataset.blurlevel = increasedLevel;
  overlay.style.backdropFilter = `blur(${increasedLevel}px)`;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <div class="overlay" data-blurlevel="0" style="backdropFilter: 'blur(0px')"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="increaseBlur()">increase</button>
```

Storing in a data attribute is of course not your only option-- you could also just maintain it in some singleton in memory, or, if you wanted, try to pull it out of the current `style.backdropFilter` value each time-- but that seems like it could be flimsy/painful.

Good luck, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much! This did work for me! I am new to JavaScript and have been self teaching. I also am new to posting on Stack Overflow. This was my first question posted so I apologize for the long post, and again, thank you for your response.

Comment: @AutumnDavis - glad it worked for you! Happy coding!