# How to change backdrop-filter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i cannot change backdrop-filter with **javascript** please help me
thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>a problem</title>
<style>
 #div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0); 
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div"></div>
</body>
<script>document.getElementById("div").style.backdropfilter = "blur(15px)";</script>
</html>
```

Comment: use `.backdropFilter` to change the value

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106689/how-can-i-change-the-backdrop-filter-i-have-set-in-css-with-javascript) pls

Comment: the modern approach is not to add inline-style but to add a class with the changes you want by using: `element.classList.add('class-name');`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use camelCase when updating CSS properties: e.g. `.backdropFilter`.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>a problem</title>
<style>
 #div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0); 
 }

 body {  background: url(https://theoldreader.com/kittens/files/images/80144273@N00-2871547320/600x400.jpg) no-repeat }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="div"></div>
</body>
<script>document.getElementById("div").style.backdropFilter = "blur(15px)";</script>
</html>
```